# DatePicker evoke in didSelectRowATIndexPath in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7

How DatePicker appers when a particular cell is clicked in a TableView. Also I need a Done button to diasapper DatePicker after use

Comment: Please post code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

in your TableViewController:

```
        var chosenNumber = 0

        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            //set your chosenNumber here based on your the cell that was clicked
           chosenNumber = 1
        }

         override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

            let controller = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController
            //the startRow variable in the ViewController with the picker is set to the same value as the chosenNumber
            controller.startRow = chosenNumber

        }
```

in your ViewController with the picker:

```
        var startRow = 0
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            //the selected item in the spinner will the value of startRow
            spinner.selectRow(startRow, inComponent: 0, animated: false)

        }
```

to hide the spinner when a button is clicked:

```
        @IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
             spinner.hidden = true
        }
```